# Unity2D fast smooth rotation around some point with 60 fps

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d, game-physics

I’m trying to implement a smooth rotation of a sprite using Unity 2D. The code is obvious:

```
void Update() {
   transform.Rotate(rotationSpeedVector * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

And it looks ok for 1 turnover, but then there is a noticeable lag with some lost frames. After 1 lag it makes one more smooth turnover, with the same lag at the end.

The lag is most noticeable on iOS devices.

What am I doing wrong? I guess it’s a common task with a simple efficient solution.

Example project : https://bitbucket.org/small_games/rotate

Comment: I didn't understand anything, can you rewrite your question and give more code please ? Remember to ident your code with 4 spaces

Comment: Sorry for my English, this version makes sense?

Comment: it's probably an issue somwhere else in your code

Comment: @broff could you test with `Time.fixedDeltaTime` instead of `Time.deltaTime` ?